# C#: How do you tell which item index is selected in ListView?

Tags: c#

C#: How do you tell which item index is selected in ListView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ListView mylistv = new ListView();
var index = mylistv.SelectedIndices();
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried SelectedIndices?

```
myListView.SelectedIndices
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SelectedIndex property of the class.